# Android: Fade text in and out within Widget

Tags: android, animation, widget, fade

How can I use a fade in and fade out effect while changing text in a widget? I have the text switching instantly but I would like to fade the text out change it and then fade it back in again. I have tried using loadAnimation, but widgets don't seem to like that.

Any help on how I can get this working will be really appreciated.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can animate a property of the TextView with [property animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Property). In your case you'd animate the [`alpha`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aalpha) property.

Since you ned to fade out, change text and then fade in, you'll need two animations.

Comment: I have been looking everywhere and can't find anything on this other than some people saying it can't be done. I have seen apps with widgets (a couple of RSS readers) that fade out and back in again when you flick through the feeds...so it must be possible, I just can't figure it out.